# Django-taggit tags with whitespace in name?

Tags: python, django, django-taggit, wagtail

How can I use tags with whitespace char in their name with django-taggit? For example, "Some simple tag"? Because if I ctrl-c=>ctrl-v some phrase to tags field in my admin panel, on page with this tag i get something like this:

```
Reverse for 'posts_by_tag' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'tag':
u'\u0411\u0430\u043d\u043a \u0422\u0430\u0432\u0440\u0438\u043a\u0430'}'
not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['blog-list/posts/(?P<tag>\\w+)$']
```

, but if I try add tag with whitespace-it just cut on whitespace char and starts new tag. How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you mean a backslash? Backtick? You can't mean backspace...

Comment: ooops, i mean space char, ty for your сcomment

Comment: I mean whitespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multi-word tags in Wagtail need to be quoted, e.g. "my tag".

There are two pull requests open that address this topic:

- https://github.com/torchbox/wagtail/issues/1874 to improve documentation and explain users that at the moment multi-word tags need to be quoted
- https://github.com/torchbox/wagtail/pull/2207 to allow multi-word tags written with spaces

Comment: Yeah, I found it, but ty for your answer. In my case was problem with url pattern, my regexp was wrong and thats why I catch this exception